# Google maps places api and express error Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, google-maps-api-3, mongoose

I am trying to use google maps places api to build a simple web application. For now am just inserting the data gotten from the api into my mongodb database.

The google maps places npm module `@google/maps` has a places method for returning data based on longitude and latitude. What i am trying to achieve is this

- When a request is made to the api route it should check the database and return some data.
- if the database is empty is should query the google maps places api for the data, insert it into the database and then perform a find request from the database.  here is my [code][1], the error is this :

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
        at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
        at ServerResponse.header (C:\Express\pizza\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:730:10)
        at ServerResponse.send (C:\Express\pizza\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
        at ServerResponse.json (C:\Express\pizza\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:256:15)
        at sendJsonResponse (C:\Express\pizza\app_api\controllers\locations.js:9:9)
        at C:\Express\pizza\app_api\controllers\locations.js:73:39
        at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Express\pizza\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3800:16)
        at C:\Express\pizza\node_modules\kareem\index.js:277:21
        at C:\Express\pizza\node_modules\kareem\index.js:131:16
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)`

if there is a better approach to solve my problem I am open to suggestions

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Location = require('../models/locations');
var googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: process.env.MAP_API_KEY
});

var sendJsonResponse = function(res, status, content) {
    res.status(status);
    res.json(content);
};
//function to filter data returned from api
var buildLocations = function(results) {
    results === Array;
    var newList = [];
    var j = 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        if (results[i].photos) {

            newList.push({
                place_id: results[i].place_id,
                name: results[i].name,
                rating: results[i].rating,
                address: results[i].formatted_address,
                photos: results[i].photos,
                location: results[i].geometry.location
            })
        }
    }
    return newList
}


//function to save data to database from api
var saveToDbFromApi = function(locations,req,res,callback){
    for(var i=0; i<locations.length; i++){
        Location.create({
            name: locations[i].name
        },function(err,locations){
            if(err){
               console.log(err);
            }
            else{
             callback(req,res);
            }
        })
    }
}



module.exports.locationList = function(req, res) {
    Location.find({}, function(err, locations) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
        }
        if (!locations.length) {
            googleMapsClient.places({
                location: [5.526679, -0.48085],
                radius: 50000,
                type: 'restaurant'
            }, function(err, response){
                if(err){
                    sendJsonResponse(res,400,err);
                }
                else{
                    var locations = buildLocations(response.json.results);
                    saveToDbFromApi(locations,req,res,function(req,res){
                        Location.find({},function(err,locations){
                            if(err){
                             console.log(err)
                            }
                            else{
       //this line brings up the 'cant set headers after they are sent error'
                             return   sendJsonResponse(res,200,locations);
                            }
                        })
                    });
                }
            })
           
        } else {
            sendJsonResponse(res, 200, locations);
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: You are trying to post data to a response that has closed. Can we see your code. The stack trace alone will not help. We need to see the server side code that is making the calls.

Comment: i posted a link to the code you can view it here [link]https://pastebin.com/bCEepQ1Z

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from the `saveToDbFromApi` function. You are iterating through a list called locations adding each location into the database; however, after each location is added, you are running the `callback(req,res);`. *You only want to run the callback once after ALL of the locations are saved to the database.*

## Here is what you have.

```
//function to save data to database from api
var saveToDbFromApi = function(locations,req,res,callback){
    for(var i=0; i<locations.length; i++){
        Location.create({
            name: locations[i].name
        },function(err,locations){
            if(err){
               console.log(err);
            }
            else{
               // this runs the callback on each iteration 
               // you need to run the callback once
               callback(req,res);

            }
        })
    }
}
```

## Here is what I recommend.

```
//function to save data to database from api
var saveToDbFromApi = function(locations,req,res,callback){

    // you might want to validate the locations is an array and has a length
    // for now we will skip of this to show you a solution

    // use a self calling recursive function
    (function saveLocation(i){

        Location.create({
            name: locations[i].name
        }, function(err,locations){

            // throw errors if any
            if(err){
                return console.error(err);
            } 

            // check if we have another location to save
            // if we do, use the recursive function to save the next one
            // if not run the callback
            if(i<locations.length){
                saveLocation(i+1); 
            } else{
                callback(req,res);
            }

        });

    })(0);

}
```

Comment: Thanks the error went away however, it returns only one location instead of three :(

Comment: I would need to see what is going on inside of `var Location = require('../models/locations');` The callback of the `Location.find({})` handles the `sendJsonResponse()` call which gives you back the data

Comment: here are the contents of the `../models/locations` file [https://pastebin.com/AhsCcPEJ]

Comment: @AmosTobi it would be best if you started a new question as to why said code is not working as the new question is outside the scope of the current.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

```
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
    }
```

If err,  It is sending a response but there is not a retun, so you could reach the line you commented and try to send headers again.